# How to give header path in iphone

Tags: ios4

How to give multiple header search path in iphone SDK? I mean what is syntax to write more than one header search path ?

I am including facebook and twitter api. These both has their own header search path.

Facebook header search path  ../facebook-iphone-sdk/src

Twiter search header path     $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2

I have to write both in header search path ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double click the input field and press the plus-button.

[image]

Comment: That is attaching with debug and Release. I want to attach with Header

Comment: Only if you push the arrow to the left. If you double click in the input field on the right you get a dialog where you can add multiple values.